# Multiple mice library?

Tags: windows

I found [TeamPlayer](https://www.dicolab.com/products_teamplayer.html) a program that supposed to allow multiple mice on one pc, is there a library to do that? or how does one would implement such a thing(Windows)

thanks.

Comment: You should edit your question to not be a request for off-site resources like libraries or it will likely be closed as off-topic. The rest of your question would probably be closed as too broad. It's better if you've tried something, show your code, and ask a narrow question about where you are having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. plug in all the mice that you intend to us.

Step 2. Install TeamPlayer ( if you install the free version. only up to 3 different mice/keyboard are usable )

Step 3. Start the software. You will notice that among all the cursors that will be on the screen, only one will have control of the window, and that one if i recall correctly will be colored.. Swapping of the mouse is done with the left click.

I hope this answers your question because i really don`t know what else your question might be referring too with "library"

Comment: I want to read the input from multiple mice, not control a window